# Sending data via socket aborts unexpected

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

i am trying to send data via tcp socket to a server. The idea behind that is a really simple chat programm.
The string I am trying to send looks like the following:

```
1:2:e9e633097ab9ceb3e48ec3f70ee2beba41d05d5420efee5da85f97d97005727587fda33ef4ff2322088f4c79e8133cc9cd9f3512f4d3a303cbdb5bc585415a00:2:xc_[z kxc_[z kxc_[z kxc_[==
```

As you can see there a few unprintable characters which I don't think are a problem here.
To send this data I am using the following code snippet.

```
bool tcp_client::send_data(string data)
{
    if( send(sock , data.c_str(), strlen(data.c_str()) , 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Send failed : ");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

After a few minutes of trying things out I came up, that data.c_str() cuts my string of.
The result is:

```
1:2:e9e633097ab9ceb3e48ec3f70ee2beba41d05d5420efee5da85f97d97005727587fda33ef4ff2322088f4c79e8133cc9cd9f3512f4d3a303cbdb5bc585415a00:2:xc_[z
```

I think that there is some kind of null sequence inside my string which is a problem for the c_str() function.

Is there a way to send the whole string as I mentioned aboved without cutting it off?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `strlen` when you have `data.length()`?

Comment: Avoid non-printable characters in strings. If it's binary, better use `std::vector<char>` for the data. You can probably get away with `send(sock, &data[0], data.legth(),...` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: In-fact I would avoid using string altogether and only accept byte arrays. Let the application level handle the converting of a string to a byte array.

Comment: And the problem *could* very well be the unprintable characters, if any of them is a binary zero it's the same as the string terminator character `'\0'`, which is what `strlen` checks for.

Comment: There is no 'abort' here. There is a difference between the actual and expected data received.

Comment: What is the point in avoiding non-printable characters in strings?  Unlike C, C++ has an actual string type, so why not use it?

Comment: Like @JoachimPileborg says, get rid of strlen().  strlen() is a huge PITA, along with all C stri... null-terminated char array code.   Nealy all C sockets code on SO has apallingly bad misuse of the horrible C 'strings' and the silly functions that fail on them, (in socket code, anyway).  Embrace C++.

Comment: @MartinJames the point is non-printable characters in strings are uncommon, which makes them surprising, and can lead to bugs like the OP's. Also, since end-users almost never input non-printable chars, this is probably binary data (semantically). Even though you can put it in a string, a vector conveys the intent better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to send the whole string as I mentioned aboved without cutting it off?

What about:

```
send(sock , data.c_str(), data.size() , 0);
```

Comment: The problem here is, that data.c_str() already cuts the string off. (I assume, that there must be a terminating sequence)

Comment: @Dominik How does `c_str()` cut the string off? all it does is retirn a pointer to its first character.

Comment: @Dominik `strlen()` cuts the length of the string at the first `null` but `data.size()` always reports the full length *including* nulls.

Comment: ^^ what @Galik says.  lets put it simply:  C++ has a string type worthy of the name, C does not.

Comment: @Dominik Are you sure its not what you do at the receiving end that is cutting it off now?

Comment: ^^^ again, I am inpressed by @Galik take on this Q&A thread. I hope the server does not have the same problem with nulls.....

Comment: Acutally you are right, data.size() does the job. But yeah as @MartinJames says, the server now having problem with nulls.

Comment: @Dominik if you wrote the server, go straight for the recv() call and anywhere around there with a str*() call.  The chances of it being correct are about the same as winning the EuroMillions lottery.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two sane ways to send arbitrary data (such as a array of characters) over stream sockets:

1. On the server: close the socket after data was sent (like in ftp, http 0.9, etc). On the client - read until socket is closed in a loop.
2. On the server: prefix the data with fixed-length size (nowadays people usualy use 64 bit integers for size, watch out for endiannes). On the client - read the size first (in a loop!), than read the data until `size` bytes are read (in a loop).

Everything else is going to backfire sooner or later.